# Evaluation of SPC rules

Tags: probability, statistics

I apologise in advance if my question sounds silly or someone might have already found a solution (of which I am not aware). The problem is quite generic and therefore I am looking for general results, such as theorems or something else.

A software for SPC I use at work allows to implement some SPC violations that execute some actions after being triggered; two of them consist in executing an action when $n$ consequent sample means are "significantly" greater/smaller than given thresholds; in particular, the trigger violations are $\mu_i>f$UCL$+(1-f)$CL and $\mu_i<f$LCL$+(1-f)$CL, where LCL$<$CL$<$UCL are some typical SPC values (namely, control limits) and $f$ is a generic real value. In this case, the hyper-parameters to set are $n$ and $f$ only. These two rules apply to each sample, namely $i=1,...,n$.

Since I have no prior information about these samples (they are just a collection of $m>0$ points; almost always, $m$ is smaller than $10$), how can I determine the probabilities Pr$(\mu_i>x_1)$ and/or Pr$(\mu_i<x_2)$, where $x_1=f$UCL$+(1-f)$CL and $x_2=f$LCL$+(1-f)$CL for the sake of simplicity? My goal is to evaluate the best $f$ that might reduce false positives/negatives in SPC detection when these violations hold.